# Increase quota per second in Google Analytics Java API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, quota

I'm trying to increase the maximum amount of requests per second in my Google Analytics API Section in Google Developers Console but I can't change the actual value (1). I think it's because I don't have billing information in my account, but this information doesn't appear in API page. Is this correct?

Also: if I add billing information, do I need to keep a subscription to keep the (hopefully) 10 requests per second quota in Analytics API?

Comment: OK that's different.  And probably a bug let me contact them

Comment: BTW you don't need billing with the Google Analytics API.

Comment: That's nice to know. So then it's a bug that I can't increase my requests per second quota?

Comment: Not right now I tested it its broken You should be able to update it to 10 but its not letting you.   I have contacted them but they are West cost USA Its probably going to be a while before I hear back.

Comment: It seems like it's sorted. Thank you!